# Cannot read property 'text' of undefined in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I created a question component. In that component I put some hard-coded questions. When I try to run the application, it shows text undefined.

Here is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-question-list',
templateUrl: './question-list.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./question-list.component.css']
})
export class QuestionListComponent implements OnInit {
questions: Object[];
constructor() {
this.questions = [
  {
    text: 'What is your name?',
    answer: 'My name is Saeef'
  },
  {
    text: 'What is your favorite color?',
    answer: 'My favorite color is blue'

 ];
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 }
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="question" *ngFor let question of questions">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        {{ question.text }}
    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
        <p class="card-text">{{ question.answer }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please recheck your array initialization and 'ngFor' statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your **`ngFor`** syntax is wrong,

It should be as,

```
<div class="question" *ngFor="let question of questions">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        {{ question.text }}
    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
        <p class="card-text">{{ question.answer }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use *ngfor and following:-
{{ question['text'] }} {{ question['answer'] }}